# Перемещение по карте двумя пальцами (в мобильной версии)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi, multi-touch, yandex-maps-embed

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно прописать в конструкторе скрипта, чтобы осуществлять перемещение по карте не одним, а **двумя** пальцами, как на прикреплённой картинке (пример: сайт [Связной](http://svyaznoy.ru/shops)). При прокрутке страницы одним пальцем перемещение было только по странице сайта, а при касании двух - перемещение по карте Яндекс. [image: Пример сайт Связной svyaznoy.ru/shops]

Answer (score 1):

Если карта сделана через JavaScript API, то её поведения можно настраивать. В Вашем случае нужно отключить поведение [перетаскивания карты](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/behavior.Drag-docpage/?from=SO) `drag`, тогда на мобильном можно будет передвигать карту только двумя пальцами.
Чтобы не перехватывать скролл страницы на десктопе, нужно отключить [поведение `scrollZoom`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/behavior.ScrollZoom-docpage/?from=SO)

Для карт, созданных в Конструкторе, можно отключить только масштабирование колесом мыши, установив параметр `scroll=false`. [Документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/constructor/concepts/About-docpage/?from=SO#interactive)

Comment: А можете подсказать как это сделать?. Где в настройках карты это сделать и чем редактировать карту?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста. В моём ответе есть ссылки на описание и примеры кода, который это делает.

Answer (score 1):

Мне известен только способ для Javascript API, в этом случае можно сделать так:

```
map.behaviors.disable('drag');
```

и в стилях:

```
.map * {
  touch-action: auto
}
```

Тогда будет и прокрутка, и перемещение с зумом двумя пальцами.
Для использования конструктора стили, очевидно, те же; а про способ отключения `drag` я не узнавал.